# Asp.Net Core With Angular Data Compression Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image]I am using lz-string to compress data in asp.net core application works fine with angular 7. But returned value size is too big (around 8 MB json data).Is there any way to reduce the size of the returned value after compression? Is there any other compression other than LZ string compression method to reduce the Json data transfer to angular 7?

Comment: can you please share some code?

Comment: ok Done   ...........................

Comment: have you solved your problem ? is GZIP stream an option ? with a gzip content-encoding ?

Comment: No. Is it better than LZ-String method?